# How to print stack in reverse?

Tags: java

```
Stack <String> stackx = new Stack<String>();
Scanner word = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner countz = new Countz(System.in);
System.out.println("How many time you want to input");
int repeat=countz.nextInt();
for (int i=0;i<repeat;i++){
     System.out.println("Data of - "+ (i+1) + ":");
     String pintri = word.nextLine();
     stackz.push(pintri);        
     }
System.out.println("Your data: "+stackx);
```

I want to print the stackx in reverse order, how to do that?
Thank you..

Comment: use another stack as intermediary. First put all in second and then extract for second. Output will be in reverse order.

Comment: @neha for ask how many times you want to input

Comment: @TraianGEICU can you give more detail, i'm beginner in java. Thank you

Comment: @BimaJordanAlfonso `new Countz(System.in)` is incorrect since there is nothing called `Countz` in java. You need to create a `Scanner` object like `Scanner countz = new Scanner(System.in);`

Comment: @neha thank you so muchh for your helpp

Answer (score 2):

You can print the reversed stack recursively:

```
void printReversed(Stack<?> stack) {
  if (stack.isEmpty()) return;

  Object value = stack.pop();
  printReversed(stack);
  System.out.println(value);
  stack.push(value); // restore the stack.
}
```

This is, of course, working by pushing values into another stack - the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

You use the pop() function to start removing the elements one by one. Stack removes element in LIFO (Last in First out), so naturally the elements will be removed (and accessed by the code) in the reverse order.

Comment: how to store the popped stack? because i want to make menu that remove the reversed stack by index

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `reverse` a `stack`,

- Create a new temporary `stack`
- You can use a `while` loop to pop the `top` element from `stackx` and push them onto the temporary stack till `stackx` becomes empty
- Print this temporary `stack`. It will contain the reversed elements.

  ```
  Stack<String> reversedStack = new Stack<>();
  while(stackx.size() > 0) {
   reversedStack(stackx.pop());
  }
  System.out.println("reversed elements: " + reversedStack);
  ```

The input and output are as below:

```
Input: How many time you want to input
3
Data of - 1:
hello
Data of - 2:
world
Data of - 3:
welcome
Your data: [hello, world, welcome]
reversed elements: [welcome, world, hello]
```

Comment: @BimaJordanAlfonso do accept the answer if it has helped answer your query. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about performance, you could `reverse` your `Stack`, print it, then reverse it back.

```
Collections.reverse(stackx);
System.out.println("Your data: " + stackx);
Collections.reverse(stackx);
```

---

On the other hand, if performance is important, you could use a `StringBuilder` to print the contents of the `Stack` data like this

```java
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for (String entry : stackx) {
    stringBuilder.insert(0, entry + ", ");
}

stringBuilder.insert(0, "[").replace(stringBuilder.length() - 2, stringBuilder.length() - 1, "]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using 2 Stacks

```
Psedudo-code

FirstStack <- add elements (push) 
//Before print
SecondStack <- add FirstStack 
(while FirstStack is not empty pop element form FirstStack and push into SecondStack
//both Stack's have the same elements but is reverse order
//print from SecondStack
(while SecondStack is not empty pop element and write on screen)
```

Also for learning purpose you could consider doing your own stack. Algorithm is the same no matter from where is taken the stack implementation.

```
import java.util.Stack;
public class TestNode {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TestNode t = new TestNode();
        //initial stack
        Stack<String> s = new Stack<String>();
        s.push("a");
        s.push("b");
        s.push("c");
        //initial stack - same results 
        //Node s = t.new Node();        
        //s.push("a");
        //s.push("b");
        //s.push("c");
        //intermediary stack
        Node n=t.new Node();
        while(!s.empty())
        {
            n.push(s.pop());
        }   
        n.print();
    }
    //custom made stack based on linked-nodes
    class Node
    {
        Node n=null;
        String data=null;
        Node()
        {
            
        }
        Node(String data, Node n)
        {
            this.data = data;
            this.n = n;
        }
        public void push(String data)
        {
            n = new Node(data,n);
        }
        public boolean empty()
        {
            if(data==null)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
        public String pop()
        {
            String out = data;
            if(out != null)
            {
                n.data = null;
                if(n.n != null)
                {
                    n = n.n;
                }
                return out;
            }
            return null;
        }
        public void print()
        {
            Node cn = n;
            while(cn != null)
            {
                System.out.println(cn.data);
                cn = cn.n; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like you do with a list. Just iterate starting with the last index to the first.

```
for (int i = stackx.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
    System.out.println(stackx.get(i));
}
```